# How do I call a Java method on button click event of JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, button

```
<p>
    <form action="logout.java" method="post">
        <input type="button" value="Logout">
    </form>
</p>
```

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
```

but when i click the button nothing happens?

Comment: Change button to submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a submit input :

```
<input type="submit" value="Logout">
```

Make sure the servlet which contains the `doPost()` method is mapped to `logout.java`. If not, you have to set the action in your form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
 }
```